# Gparted/parted/gdisk/fdisk all pretend to create partition table?

Tags: gparted, fdisk, parted

I have been trying to wipe and reset an entire HDD. Something went wrong when moving a drive from Windows to Ubuntu. So in the midst of a tutorial or two.. I wiped the whole drive.

Here's the rub: I wipe the drive and then use 'parted' to create a new partition table and partition. All goes swimmingly well until I quit `parted` and open it back up again to print the details or the new partition table - which turn out to be `unknown`.

```
david@davidp:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1 
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.0190629 s, 26.9 kB/s
david@davidp:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdc
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel gpt                                                      
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 0G 2900G                                    
(parted) print
Model: ATA TOSHIBA HDWD130 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  2900GB  2900GB  ext4         primary

(parted) quit                                                             
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

david@davidp:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdc                                      
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Error: /dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA TOSHIBA HDWD130 (scsi)                                         
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Disk info:

```
david@davidp:~$ sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Same behaviour with gdisk, fdisk as well. I can't use Gparted - cause when I try to create the partition table using the GUI is bombs with the standard - "disk label is unknown". I have trawled the net and this site for similar issues for the last 4 days. - but it seems everyone has been able to create the partition table successfully - not me.

any help would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: To be clear I asked this question on stack and a gentlement replied wit the use of `dd` which I added above. It "worked" in that gparted was able to see the partition table and partition I create in the terminal. But then I tried to format that partition - and it went back to `unknown disk label` :/

Comment: Is this sdc? and did you use Windows to partition it originally? Or try to use MBR. Drives over 2TiB, need to use gpt partitioning, so disk label must be gpt.  In gparted, first thing is to select gpt under device, advanced & select gpt over msdos(MBR) default partitioning.... Or
`sudo parted /dev/sdc mklabel gpt`

Comment: It is indeed sdc. It was partitioned on windows years ago. 
I have run that command: `sudo parted /dev/sdc mklabel gpt` and also tried using Gparted. Gparted fails loudly and tells me something went wrong. parted - doesn't. All choosing GPT over any other table type. I've run the parted commands both in the repl and externally like you suggested with the same results.

Comment: Sometimes gdisk works on gpt drives when parted does not. Did your try gdisk? repair gpt:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html

Comment: yes,  done this. same thing. no errors. all just writes and exits, but actually does nothing. no partitions or partition table available after operation. I don't need to recover anything from this disk. Is there any way I can just rebuild the drive from scratch? or is this exactly what we're doing?

Comment: That should be what we are doing. If your are sure there is nothing to recover, then you can use dd to erase beginning of drive, or whole drive, but whole drive should not be required. When you plug in flash drive devive letters change, so be sure you have correct drive. 'sudo parted -l` then this which is mkusb and helps double check you are using correct drive for dd (which you do not see): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Wipe_the_first_megabyte_or_the_whole_device

Comment: When "_GParted fails loudly_", what does the message say?  If the message indicates an input/output error with the drive then that might indicate a hardware problem.

Comment: It fails loudly - in that is actually gives me feedback saying the process didn't not complete. But I do not get any such error or response to stdout when I use parted(in the terminal).